# How to dynamically style text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm showing larger strings in 4-character chunks:

```
abcd 2345 3456 efgh
```

But instead of using whitespace characters, I'm using `span` and `margin-right`. This way the user can copy & paste the number without the unnecessary extra spaces.

```
<span class="chunk">abcd</span>
<span class="chunk">2345</span>
...
```

```js
.chunk {
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Now I would like to have a text input field which groups the numbers the same way while the user inputs the number or while she pastes a number into the form.

```
<input id="numberInput1" type="text"/>
```

What is the current best practice to achieve this behavior? I'm looking for a solid solution which isn't too obscure and doesn't cause horrible accessibility issues.

Comment: The term is called 'input masking'. Here's the first hit in google for a suitable plugin: http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/. Click the demo link to see it in action.

Comment: You could trigger a function with `onkeypress` and count the letters on the input field and add a space character when there the 4th digit is inserted. You may want to use `str.replace(" ","") after. I don't know if this is the most solid way to do it, though.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique Thanks for your comment. However -  as stated in my question - I don't want to insert actual whitespace characters. Imho this would just lead to a plethora of negative consequences.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with a [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) element. As far as I know input - without the white-spaces - are not styleable.

You can then parse the numbers pasted into the element and re-render them as styled markup.

Pretty fancy stuff, worth playing around with. =)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I followed the approach you suggested. Styling the editable div so it looks like an input field and inserting _spans_ via javascript *works like a charm*. However, everytime I change .innerHTML, the position of the caret resets. Dealing with this leads to all kinds of cross-browser range and selection issues. It's doable, but is this really the way to go?

Comment: @armin You are basically creating a custom editable field for your own needs so you will need to control the caret on your own. I would expect this being controlled by a *Backbone.View*, *React.Component*, *Ember.Component*, etc. where you can memorize the caret placement before you do anything with the innerHTML of the contenteditable. You can create a in-memory buffer input element for your widget and preserve the selection related functionality there.

Comment: I can't introduce a complex js framework just for this little task (ember.js has like 15k+ loc), so i guess I will have to build my own little select&range function. I guess there is no way around it. **Secretly I hoped there would be a simpler solution**, like some kind of new, pure CSS trick, something like _:first-letter_, but for the nth-character. One can always dream…

Comment: @armin You can create a contenteditable View/Component, pure and VanillaJS, the main idea is that you have the whole selection/range functionality there. =) **Fun fact:** there is no simple and elegant to any front-end related problem, people either want to go down the Java/Python?Ruby way or just want to hack their ways around with jQuery. Sweet dreams! =))